# In Meteor, when insecure package is removed, is Collection.find allowed on the client?

Tags: meteor

I understand that modifications to the Collections are not allowed when 'insecure' package is removed. So, what operations are allowed without the 'insecure' package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the insecure pacakage means you no longer have full unrestricted access to the database. If you have autopublish still present, you will be able to search for records but not update/create unless you grant permissions explicitly.

Once you remove autopublish, you will need to publish data yourself, and also subscribe to the data on the client. A little more work, but important performance wise once you start growing your data.

There is a good explanation on Meteor security here https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/

Comment: So, assuming you have published a collection C to client, C.find() will work fine even without the insecure package ?

Comment: This is correct - `.find()` does not depend on `insecure`. The `autopublish` package determines whether or not you need to setup publications and subscriptions. You really should remove both packages very early in development.